# USMap Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I am using USMap plugin from this site: http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/. I have included all the js files and I can see the map in my page.
But the code for getting the state names of clicked state is not working.

This is the .js code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#map').usmap({
// The click action
 click: function(event, data) {
  $('#clicked-state')
   .text('You clicked: '+data.name)
   .parent().effect('highlight', {color: '#C7F464'}, 2000);
 }
  });
   });

  <p:panel id="USmap" header="USMap">
    <div id="clicked-state">hi</div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div> 

  </p:panel>
```

Also i wanted to pass the state name to backing bean. Im using primefaces. How can i do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify your script links. You may want try putting your script after the ui control.

You may have to put the raphael.js file in a folder called, 'libs', if your running the scripts local.

Here is the //jsfiddle.net/f4HWX/